# CSS3 Flexbox for responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox

MAJ : adding a codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/srGwq

I start to deal with flexbox for a very specific project. As the docs changed frequently from many times I don't deal with my problem.

Here is my html :

```
<div class="flexbox">
    <div class="middle">Middle</div>
    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

And my css (without prefixes for lisibility) :

```
.flexbox {
  display: box;
  box-orient: horizontal;
  box-align: start;
}

.middle {
  box-flex-group: 1;
  box-flex: 2;
  box-ordinal-group: 2;
}

.left {
  box-flex-group: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
  box-ordinal-group: 1;
}

.right {
  box-flex-group: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
  box-ordinal-group: 3;
}
```

So, the result is this :

```
________________________
| .left .middle .right |
|______________________|
```

With media queries, I change box-ordinal-group and box-orient to get this result on mobile :

```
____________
| .middle  | 
| .left    |
| .right   |
|__________|
```

So the problem is, I need to put .left and .right aligned vertically in a single left column on tablet, like this :

```
____________________
| .left   .middle  | 
| .right           |
|__________________|
```

I tried to put .left and .right to  box-ordinal-group:1 and set .middle to box-orginal-group:2 but the result is that the .left and .right are aligned on the left horizontally, and i would them to be aligned vertically.

As i do not know Flexbox very well, you experience would be welcome. Maybe it's just not possible.

Thanks, and sorry for the bad schemas, I did not earn the possibility to post image yet.

Answer (score 0):

see the flex-flow property:

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox/#flex-flow-property

pseudo code like this:

@media $QUERY_TABLET { .flexbox {flex-flow: row wrap} }

Answer (score 0):

I put some examples on my [github bredele](http://github.com/bredele%22github%22) of wrap layout. You should get what you want by playing with flex-flow (row/column wrap) and flex-basis (initial min-width).

With row wrap flow:

```
.flexbox {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.left, .right {
    -webkit-flex: 1 50%;
    flex: 1 50%;
}

.middle {
    width:50%;
}
```

With column wrap flow:

```
.flexbox {
    /* the height has to be defined */
    height:400px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display:flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.left, .right {
    -webkit-flex: 1 50%;
    flex: 1 50%;
}

.middle {
    -webkit-flex: 1 100%;
    flex:1 100%;
}
```

I think the second solution is what you are looking for.

Olivier :)